# Jquery .attr passing & in link as &amp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, joomla

On a `joomla` site i am working on we use jquery to change a button that goes to our checkout page.

```
cartlink = "https://domain.co.uk/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=67&domainoption=subdomain&sld=domain&tld=.co.uk&billingcycle=monthly&configoption[2]="+configoption2+"&configoption[3]="+configoption3+"&configoption[5]="+configoption5;

    jQuery("a#vps").attr('href', '' + cartlink +'');
```

However when someone clicks the link they are redirected to

```
https://domain.co.uk/billing/cart.phpa=add&amp;pid=67&amp;domainoption=subdomain&amp;sld=domain&amp;tld=.co.uk&amp;billingcycle=monthly&amp;configoption[2]=7&amp;configoption[3]=9&amp;configoption[5]=14
```

Notice that the & signs are sent as `&amp;` . Our billing system doesnt pick up & in the url can anybody help

Regards Ross

Comment: Are you sure that's how it looks *when the page is rendered*? The source you're looking at may be getting encoded again before rendered to the client, check the source the client's actually getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540106/change-href-parameter-using-jquery/6540126#6540126 check the first answer out

Comment: How do i go about checking this i just want a fix been at this all day

Comment: Looks like your joomla is being helpful and html encoding the ampersands instead of leaving them alone. It isn't clear to me why the question mark between php and a=add is being removed.

Comment: Any ideas on how to stop joomla doing this

Answer (score 0):

The change is done server side as the code you posted works perfectly when fiddled, see http://jsfiddle.net/nzz3w/ . So it's not possible(atleast for me) to debug without knowing what's going on at server side...

Comment: Hi Erric thanks for your answer so how can i go about letting you know what happens server side