# jQuery replace href value but only partially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change href parameter using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540106/change-href-parameter-using-jquery)

I have a page with several links like this:

```
<a href="playcats.php?cat='.$catname.'&sl=10" class="golink">
```

So after PHP page loads it will look like:

```
<a href="playcats.php?cat=blue&sl=10" class="golink">
<a href="playcats.php?cat=red&sl=10" class="golink">
<a href="playcats.php?cat=yellow&sl=10" class="golink">
...
```

I want partially change the href for the sl value of all links using jQuery (sl value is picked from a slider = data.value)

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.golink').each(function() {
    var _href = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $(this).  ( rest of code.. )
  } );
});
```

And now I do not know how to use replace with regular expressions as I think it is the solution!

Comment: your first link, is it getting print through a loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might do

```
 $(this).attr('href', _href.replace(/sl=[^&]+/, 'sl=newval'));
```

to replace the value of `sl` by 'newval'.

You can also use a function to build the new value. For example, say you want to multiply by 2 the old sl value, you may do this :

```
 $(this).attr('href', _href.replace(/sl=([^&]+)/, function(_, oldval) {
      return 'sl='+(2*parseInt(oldval,10))
 }));
```

You may even avoid using `each` :

```
$('a.golink').attr('href', function(i, v){
  return v.replace(/sl=([^&]+)/, function(_, oldval) {
      return 'sl='+(2*parseInt(oldval,10))
  })
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/srjPu/) (over the links to see the href)

Comment: so great dystroy ! ... works perfectly.
And also many thanks for the extra function showed here, might also be usefull for my project.
Thanks !!

Comment: @PedroP See also the third solution I gave, avoiding the each.

Comment: ty again dystroy, do you believe is better to use this third solution instead the each way ?

Comment: Personally I prefer this solution but you might have other things to do in your `each` and I don't think this matters a lot.

Comment: I will use this third solution then because there is not anything more to do in the each. It is only to make this href replace. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about using the overload of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) that takes a callback function:

```
$("a.golink").attr("href", function (_, val) {
    return val.replace(/sl=\d+/gi, "sl=new_value");
});
```

Inside of the function, `this` is equal to the current `<a>` tag, so you could determine what value to use there.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/5/

Answer (score 2):

Try this, long code for understanding...

```
$('a').each(function(){
    // Change this to get slider value
    slider_value = 25;

    var _href = $(this).attr('href'); 
    _href = _href.split("&");
    _href[_href.length] = "sl=" + slider_value;
    _href = _href.join("&");

    console.log(_href);
});
```

Using regex:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    // Change this to get slider value
    slider_value = 25;

    var _href = $(this).attr('href'); 
    _href = _href.replace(/sl=[^&]+/, 'sl=' + slider_value);
});
```